# Como pegar dados de um formulário e jogar em um Array PHP

Tags: php, java, android

Tenho uma aplicação Android, que cria um arquivo em TXT no PHP, trazendo os dados do formulário XML do próprio Android. Vejam o código:

```
$f = fopen('POST_DATA.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($f, 'ID: '.$id."\r\n");
    $id = uniqid( time() );
    fwrite($f, 'Nome: '.$_POST['nome']."\r\n");
    fwrite($f, 'Cpf: '.$_POST['cpf']."\r\n");
    fwrite($f, 'Bairro: '.$_POST['bairro']."\r\n");
    fwrite($f, 'E-mail: '.$_POST['email']."\r\n");
    fwrite($f, 'Telefone: '.$_POST['telefone']."\r\n\r\n");

    fclose($f);
```

Gostaria de jogar os dados nome, cpf, bairro, email e telefone em um array, que retorne os seguintes dados, pois a consulta abaixo já consigo ler ela em Android:

```
$json_str = '{"usuarios": '.'[{"nome":"Felipe", "bairro": São Pedro, "cpf": "11111111", "email" : "teste@hotmail.com", "telefone" : "222222222"},'.']}'; 
//faz o parsing da string, criando o array "empregados" 
$jsonObj = json_decode($json_str); $empregados = $jsonObj->empregados; 
    echo $json_str;
```

Comment: por que não salva o próprio json no arquivo txt? pega alguma biblioteca/função que identa ele ao salvar no txt.

Answer (score 1):

Não seria mais fácil já trazer esses dados em formato json do seu app Android e só ler com json_decode?

Se não for possível, faça com uma regex:

```
$linhas = file('POST_DATA.txt');
$ret = array();
foreach ($linhas as $val) {
    preg_match('/^([\w-]+?): ?(.*)/', $val, $matches);
    if (count($matches) === 0) {
        continue; // linha inválida
    }

     $ret[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
}
var_dump($ret);
```